# Importing Excel Data With Images into SQL Server

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I wish to import data from an Excel File into SQL Server 2012. The Excel file has one column which contains an image in each row.

So when I use the SQL Server Import & Export Wizard, it imports everything fine except the pictures.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to import images from an Excel file into SQL Server using the Import & Export Wizard.

This is partly due to the fact that images are actually not located inside the individual spreadsheet cells. In Excel, images are stored as free objects (granted, you can anchor an image to a cell, but this is pure layout - not data).

To be able to do what you want, you'd probably have to create some custom VBA code, to loop through each image in your spreadsheet, serialize the image into binary format and then write it to your SQL database table, along with the name of the image object. You will probably have to do this on an image-by-image basis, inserting one record at a time, so hopefully, your Excel spreadsheet does not contain too many images.

Binding each image record to the cell record will be a problem on its own, but hopefully, the images in your Excel file have been named in a way, that enables you to match them with their corresponding data record.